# How to prove these type of questions of Big O notation?

Tags: data-structures

Let f(n) = 5n 3 + 3n 2 + 10 and g(n) = 3n 2 +2n + 5. Prove that f(n) is not O(g(n)) but g(n) is O(f(n)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Definition:**

> f(n) = O(g(n)) if there exists a positive integer n0 and a positive
>   constant c, such that f(n)≤c.g(n) ∀ n≥n0

you can check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithms-big-o-analysis/) for more.
in this case f(n) = 5n 3 + 3n 2 + 10 and g(n) = 3n 2 +2n + 5
there is no, n0 possible for `f(n)≤c.g(n)` so `f(n)=O(g(n))` is not possible for large `n's`.
but for  `g(n)≤c.f(n)` `n0` is possible so `g(n) = O(f(n))` is possible.

example: n0=2 and c=1 for all `n's` greater than 2 `g(n)≤c.f(n)` condition is always true.